# automatically append executable line to script files

Tags: ruby, scripting, executable

My hosting company requires me to put `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby` at the top of every RB file. Is there an easy way to use sed recursively or something that can go through and append this to the top of every rb file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk

```
$ awk 'NR==1{$0="#!/usr/local/bin/ruby\n"$0 }1' file > temp; mv temp file;
```

sed

```
sed -i.bak '1 i #!/usr/local/bin/ruby' file
```

to do it recursively, you can use find

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.rb" | while read -r FILE
do
    sed -i.bak '1 i #!/usr/local/bin/ruby' $FILE 
    # awk 'NR==1{$0="#!/usr/local/bin/ruby\n"$0 }1' >temp ; mv temp $FILe
done
```